# ¿El objeto process.env.NODE_ENV solo existe en ambiente de producción (o sea servidores)?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, variables-de-configuración

Estoy tratando de descifrar cómo funciona, estoy utilizando `process.env.NODE_ENV` como bandera para definir en ambiente de desarrollo o produccion.

Lo único que hago es prácticamente esto:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV){
    // hacer A
}else {
    hacer B
}
```

Pero realmente no entiendo, ¿El `process.env.NODE_ENV` solo existe en servidores? ¿Por qué en mi máquina si trato de imprimirlo al iniciar, obtengo un `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda que un servidor no es mas que una maquina con especificaciones particulares para recibir muchas solicitudes. Según la documentación de node, el atributo env del objeto process retorna un objeto que tiene información sobre el entorno de configuración de la maquina donde se este corriendo el programa. Vamos a intentar un ejemplo, ¿Que pasaría si imprimimos solo el objeto process.env sin configurar ningún entorno? ¿Que devolvería?

[image: Objeto process.env]

(nota: object.keys() devuelve una lista con las llaves del objeto, esto a fin de acortar y no tener un diccionario muy largo en la foto)

Todas esas son las variables de entorno de la maquina donde se corre el proceso.

Una vez que sabemos eso, NODE_ENV seria una variable (estándar) para detectar si el proceso se esta corriendo en modo desarrollo o produccion. Para eso hay dos valores estándar y son "development" y "production"

Sabiendo esto, puedes configurar una variable global en el sistema a traves de comandos (o incluso archivos con varias variables):

PowerShell (Windows):

```
$env:VARIABLE="valor"
```

Bash/Shell (Ubuntu):

```
export VARIABLE="valor"
```

¿Como puedo identificar en mi programa correctamente si el entorno es de desarrollo o producción? Bueno, una forma es partiendo del hecho de que si el servidor esta en producción tendrá esta variable de entorno configurada con el valor "production" Entonces:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
```

Si es verdadero, estas en entorno de producción, si no, estas en entorno de desarrollo (o no se ha configurado y por defecto seria desarrollo)